# Resizing views in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder, nsview

I'm having trouble visualizing something.

Let say I have three views inside a scrollview with some other content. Top, buttons and image. buttons and image are both inside top. Top does NOT fill up the scrollview, however, buttons and image DO fill up top. Top has a maximum size determined at runtime, but it might not all be visible. The buttons view is above the image view. The buttons view should have a fixed height, but stretch width wise. The image view should fill up the topview and stretch in both directions.

The question is what happens when the window with the scrollview resizes, and when the scrollview scrolls.

I want whenever any part of the topview is visible, for the buttonview to be at the top of the visible portion of topView, and I want the imageview to take up whatever space (if any) is available below it. Even if I'm scrolling, or resizing the outer window.

I currently have in IB:
TopVew doesn't resize at all, locked top and left.
ButtonView resizes width but not height and is locked top left
ImageView resizes both,and is locked top bottom left. (probably adding right wouldn't matter)

What's happening is that when I scroll, the whole thing just scrolls, so buttonview goes off the top, and when I make the window too small, the imageview covers the buttonview. It then doesn't UNCOVER it when I make the window bigger or scroll or anything.

Is there something simple that I'm missing here?

thanks.

Comment: It might be worth posting your xib file somewhere and/or posting screenshots of the issue. It's difficult to visualise what you're getting at.

Comment: Well, I can probably post the xib, but that's sort of only part of the problem. The real context is as part of a Mozilla plugin, so the REAL window and outer scrollview are really the firefox window.... but you can still see the imageview covering buttonview issue. How do I post my xib?